# mongoose query does not return the location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is one record in my document, which contains location field that I need to fetch.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "559c152fa439a961c357f931"
    },
    "POST_ID": "354-20160",
    "MS_ID": "-",
    "MS_SPACEID": 0,
    "CAP_COLOR": "Grey",
    "METER_TYPE": "SS",
    "SMART_METE": "Y",
    "ACTIVESENS": "N",
    "JURISDICTI": "SFMTA",
    "ON_OFF_STR": "ON",
    "OSP_ID": 0,
    "STREET_NUM": 2016,
    "STREETNAME": "CHESTNUT ST",
    "STREET_SEG": 3977000,
    "RATEAREA": "Area 5",
    "SFPARKAREA": "Marina",
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            37.8007983983,
            -122.4368696024
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is how i defined the schema in mongoose

```
// mongoose scehma
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var parkingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "POST_ID": String,
    "MS_ID": String,
    "MS_SPACEID": Number,
    "CAP_COLOR": String,
    "METER_TYPE": String,
    "SMART_METE": String,
    "ACTIVESENS": String,
    "JURISDICTI": String,
    "ON_OFF_STR": String,
    "OSP_ID": Number,
    "STREET_NUM": Number,
    "STREETNAME": String,
    "STREET_SEG": Number,
    "RATEAREA": String,
    "SFPARKAREA": String,
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": String,
        "coordinates": [Number]
    }
});

var Parking = mongoose.model('parking_info', parkingSchema);
module.exports = Parking;
```

My query that returns the records :

```
app.get("/parkings", function(req, res){
    Parking.find(function(err, parkings){
        if(err){
            console.log('error..');
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('returning parkings..');
            res.send( parkings);
        }

    });

});
```

gives :

```
    [
{"_id":"559c152fa439a961c357f931","POST_ID":"354-20160","MS_ID":"-","MS_SPACEID":0,"CAP_COLOR":"Grey","METER_TYPE":"SS","SMART_METE":"Y","ACTIVESENS":"N","JURISDICTI":"SFMTA","ON_OFF_STR":"ON","OSP_ID":0,"STREET_NUM":2016,"STREETNAME":"CHESTNUT ST","STREET_SEG":3977000,"RATEAREA":"Area 5","SFPARKAREA":"Marina"},
{"_id":"559c1530a439a961c357f932","POST_ID":"354-21030","MS_ID":"-","MS_SPACEID":0,"CAP_COLOR":"Green","METER_TYPE":"SS","SMART_METE":"Y","ACTIVESENS":"N","JURISDICTI":"SFMTA","ON_OFF_STR":"ON","OSP_ID":0,"STREET_NUM":2103,"STREETNAME":"CHESTNUT ST","STREET_SEG":3979000,"RATEAREA":"Area 5","SFPARKAREA":"Marina"},
{"_id":"559c1530a439a961c357f933","POST_ID":"354-21160","MS_ID":"-","MS_SPACEID":0,"CAP_COLOR":"Yellow","METER_TYPE":"SS","SMART_METE":"Y","ACTIVESENS":"N","JURISDICTI":"SFMTA","ON_OFF_STR":"ON","OSP_ID":0,"STREET_NUM":2116,"STREETNAME":"CHESTNUT ST","STREET_SEG":3979000,"RATEAREA":"Area 5","SFPARKAREA":"Marina"},
{"_id":"559c1530a439a961c357f934","POST_ID":"363-05250","MS_ID":"-","MS_SPACEID":0,"CAP_COLOR":"Grey","METER_TYPE":"SS","SMART_METE":"N","ACTIVESENS":"N","JURISDICTI":"SFMTA","ON_OFF_STR":"ON","OSP_ID":0,"STREET_NUM":525,"STREETNAME":"COLUMBUS AVE","STREET_SEG":4295000,"RATEAREA":"Area 3","SFPARKAREA":""}
...
```

Why is location not in query results? Could someone help me fix this.

Comment: Have you not created any index on the location field?

Comment: no i haven't yet, but do i need to ? i am not searching by coordinates, i am just finding all documents right now. shouldn't the location show up as well ?

Comment: If you are not doing geo based queries then you don't need an index. Have a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the declaration of the LOCATION field:

```
var parkingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": String,           //Mongoose assumes the field is of String type.
        "coordinates": [Number]
    }
});
```

You can correct this by doing:

```
var parkingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": {"type": String},           
        "coordinates": [Number]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked.. but i still don't get it . is type a keyword in mongoose or something ?

Comment: Yes, an object with the type field is another way of specifying the properties of a schema field in Mongoose. For eg. `email: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true}` or `createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}`. This way is used when other characteristics for the schema field need to be specified as well.